# In what contexts is the phrase "a recent point" used?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, meaning

There are many kinds of point, but is there a recent point?

I can imagine this sort of phrase occurring in a discussion or lecture regarding subject matter that was referenced somehow not too long ago.  However, never heard it in speech, although it doesn't sound bad.
Does this phrase occur in English?

Comment: A quick google for "a recent point" returns a number of hits in a variety of contexts, including this question.

Comment: I get one same result twice on the second page in the sense of @Justin's answer. Google's personalization at work

Comment: [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+recent+point&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20recent%20point%3B%2Cc0) might give an alternative to Google's personalisation.

Comment: @Pam that's interesting, but it doesn't give examples.  Is there a way to search the corpus for examples?

Comment: @Artemmm, if you look below the graph, the years (e.g. 1997-2000) are actually links. Click on those, and it comes out looking like a google search of the books with the examples in the description. Not sure if that's personalised or not since you're searching a finite corpus of text.

Comment: @Pam ok, thanks, got the links.  Not sure what you mean by personalized here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I occurs frequently, as in [Into Thin Air](https://books.google.com/books?id=_XGM-ntQ_uAC&lpg=PT77&dq=%22recent%20point%22%20phrase&pg=PT77#v=onepage&q=%22recent%20point%22%20phrase&f=false) google books

> He nodded. “That's great! That means Amanda is alive.” Or at least she
>   was at some recent point.

Answer (score 1):

"*A recent point*" can be interpreted as "*a recent point in time*".

If this phrase were to be written using a single word, the word would be "*recently*".

So you can imagine what it literally means.

Therefore, the answer is yes. It does occur in English. By using "*recently*", you are actually referring to a *recent point* in time, and vice versa.